# Azure returns bearer token even with incorrect password

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have the following method to get a bearer token to access my web api:

```
const string authority = "some url";
const string resourceUri = "http://api/";
const string clientId = "some client id";

var ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
var userCredential = new UserCredential(username, password);            
var ar = ac.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientId, userCredential);           
var authHeader = ar.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
```

The first time that a client authenticates, the username and the password need to be the same. The second time is different - if I pass in a real username and password, or a real username and a fake password, the result is the same. The only time that it doesn't work properly is if the username is invalid. Any idea what is causing token requests past the first to not authenticate fully using the password? It looks like it's entirely based off of the username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd time you are hitting the cache.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to go about not hitting the cache?

Comment: Yep! You can clean up the cache explicitly, via myAuthContext.TokenCache.Clear(). You can even delete just the entry for this particular user if you want to preserve the rest of the cache. Or you can initialize a new authenticationcontext and pass null to the constructor in place of the t cache as this will create a context without backing cache. I am interested in your scenario, if you have a chance of describing it that would be super useful! Thanks

Comment: Ironically, I think I actually sent you a message about the android ADAL library from the contact us form on the website. I'd prefer to keep the details of it off the public domain if you want to just respond to that directly. Your suggestion worked for me by using the constructor to null out the token cache, so thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out! Re: details, totally understandable. I searched my inbox but could not find a msg from the site regarding Android ADAL... if you have any chance of resending that would be awesome - otherwise nevermind, I just wanted to make sure you're unblocked. Thanks